How fast are Minovsky Particles?
In Mobile Suit Gundam, one of the main drivers of a lot of the technology is based off of the Minovsky Particle, a versatile particle that serves as energy sources, radar jammers, and for beam weaponry. My question mainly revolves around the beam weaponry application of the Minovksy Particle: how fast can these particles move? This might be a misunderstanding of particle physics on my part, but would all beam weaponry fire at the same speed, or would there be different accelerations based on the emitting technology used? They're certainly slow enough to be dodged (though mostly seen dodged/blocked by newtypes, people with inhuman reaction speeds), but my best guess is that handheld weaponry that a lot of Mobile Suits use simply fires them slowly enough to be reasonably avoided, rather than instantaneous.

Per the wiki article you've linked, Minovsky particles have a tiny but non-zero rest mass, and so (at least under IRL Relativity) must travel slower than the speed of light.  The speed of any beam or signal would thus depend on the kinetic energy imparted to the particles, though if their mass is small enough (eg. neutrinos) any meaningful amount of energy would have them traveling very close to c.

They move at the speed of plot
